# Overwrite variables if condition is met, else keep existing values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Considering the following code:

```
def overwrite(condition):
    if condition:
        return "bar"

foo = "foo"
foo = overwrite(False)
print(foo) # -> this should print "foo"
```

From the function perspective, we don't know the value of `foo` unless it's explicitly passed as an argument to the function. I don't want to pass it because in my case this function is already very crowded and it doesn't look very pythonic this way.

Is there any way to NOT overwrite the variable and keep its original value?

Comment: How about `if condition: foo = "bar"`?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything if `condition == False` thus `print(foo)` outputs `None`

Comment: `foo = overwrite(False) or foo`

Comment: How on earth could `overwrite(False)` know what value to return? Even if you could somehow make this work, you absolutely shouldn't under any circumstances. Inventing black magic which violates all expectations about how functions should behave is not Pythonic.

Comment: I know it doesn't return anything if this condition is False. This part was not implemented to get your solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it. When you assign, as in

```
foo = overwrite(False)
```

python fully resolves the right hand side to a value, and then does the assignment on the left. And that assignment could be more complicated, like

```
baz[10] = overwrite(False)
qux.quux = overwrite(False)
pandas_df["random column"] = overwrite(False)
```

The function has no idea where its return value will go so can't get its original value. And it can't stop python from doing the assignment. Your function is complicated, but this is a complication that's needed.

EDIT

As noted by others, you could let the calling code decide whether to update `foo`

```
foo = val if (val := overwrite(False)) is not None else foo
```

Now `overwrite` doesn't care if you overwrite or not, it just returns `None` when it didn't generate a settable value.

You could also create a more complicated return object that lets `overwrite` return its value and whether there should be an update.

```
class OverwriteResult:
    
    def __init__(self, overwrite, result):
        self.overwrite = overwrite
        self.result = result
        
    def get(self, default):
        return self.result if self.overwrite else default
    
def overwrite(condition):
    if condition:
        return OverwriteResult(True, "bar")
    return OverwriteResult(False, None)

foo = "foo"
result = overwrite(False)
foo = result.get(foo)
```

I'm not sure if that's cool or overkill.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was expecting to hear. I was wondering if there is a way to do this or not. However, if I move the if condition outside of the function and call the function inside if condition, that would do it?

Comment: Kindof. The example `foo = overwrite(False) or foo` works when you return a truthy value like "bar". But suppose you want to return `0`. Its got a false value, so `foo` would not change. You could do a ternary operation with the walrus operator: `foo = val if (val := overwrite(False) is not None) else foo`. Now the onlly problematic return is `None`. `overwrite` would be restricted from returning `None` except when its the "do not replace" case.

Comment: Thanks for the making me aware of the None problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default functions implicitly return `None` if not explicitly returned in the code. Thus you get `None` if `condition` is `False`. Try using the a ternary return statement and supply the function the value to be changed:

```
def overwrite(value, condition):
    return "bar" if condition else value
```

Then to call the function:

```
>>> foo = overwrite(foo, False)
'foo'
>>> foo = overwrite(foo, True)
'bar'
```

If you wish not to call having to supply the value then you can use the `global` keyword to access `foo`'s value from inside the function. Although I do not suggest writing code in this fashion, as now you have a generic seeming function `overwrite` that only works for one value.

```
def overwrite(condition, value=None):
    global foo
    return "bar" if condition else value or foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mentioned that I would like to avoid to pass the argument.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: That last one assumes "foo" in the function's global namespace. Something like `baz = overwirte(False)` would cause `foo` to change.

Comment: I wouldn't use globals either.